# How to add or commit files to assembla repository from linux?

Tags: linux, remote, svn, commit-charge

I know how to commit a file and add a file on a linux svn but how do I commit or add a file to my assembla svn from linux ?

Let's say I am working on my project:

```
svn co https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/my_project/trunk
```

so I have:

```
/root/trunk
```

Now I have made a new file into it, let's call it fileX:

```
/root/trunk/fileX
```

- **What options do I have to add or commit that file to my assembla
  project FROM LINUX ?**

I have tried to create the file inside the trunk folder and run the below commands without success:

```
svn add fileX
svn up
svn ci
```

**UPDATE:**

```
root@server:/test/trunk# svn add index.pl
A         index.pl
root@server:/test/trunk# svn ci
root@server:/test/trunk#
```

I hope my question looks clear and that this could be asked here other wise I kindly ask it to be moved to the right SX network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembla provides standard Subversion as a hosted service.

If you can check out the project as you write, then the commands you list for adding and committing a file should also work. There is probably something else going wrong.

What output do you get from `svn add fileX; svn ci`? Any error messages? What makes you believe the commands failed?

*Edit:*

If `svn add` works as expected, but `svn ci` just does nothing, then check:

- Does Subversion actually show the file as modified? Make sure it is listed with "M" if you do `svn status`.
- `svn ci` will invoke an editor for the commit message if you don't provide one. Try giving a commit message explicitly (`-m "first commit"`), to see if there's a problem with launching the editor.

Comment: update the question with what the commands output, thanks for the input.

Comment: Sorry forget to mention, after doing both commands browsed assembla and no files were there nor anything that is why.

Comment: Seems like the problem was the editor, using -m worked just fine for some reason ... at the worst I was expecting an error to show up or something but nothing came up. thanks for the help :)